# Installing packages in R for android

Tags: android, r, installation, package, terminal-ide

I have rooted my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 just to run R. I run R  in "Terminal IDE" as superuser.
I am not able to install any package (no package! Nothing, zero!) with the function install.packages("whatever library") always render to the message "Warning message: In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib): package 'whatever library' is not available (for R version 2.13.0)"

Comment: Your R version is ancient. Can you install the current version (R 3.0.2)?

Comment: [How to install old packages](http://christophergandrud.blogspot.com/2013/02/installoldpackages-repmis-command-for.html)

Comment: Have you defined the library path? What does `.libPaths()` return?

Comment: @geotheory I got the following directory: /data/local/gcc/lib/R/library

Comment: So its a valid path. But I think Roland and Ricardo are on the right track.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Thank you, for your suggestion! but as stated before. I cannot install ANY package! InstallOldPackages() function is part of "repmis" library, which I can not install!

Comment: @Kedarnath I see you've edited many `r` questions to `r.java-file` questions. Please pay attention where `r` is actually the correct tag to use.

Comment: @laalto Opps, My mistake.